# Is there a higher order replacement for do.call(rbind, ...)?

Tags: r

Consider the following data frame `A`

```
A <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), num = c(6,2,8,3,3,1))
```

With `A`, I'd like to split on `ID`, then calculate the difference in `num`.   The desired result can (almost) be obtained with

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x) { x$new <- c(diff(x$num), NA); x }, 
                   split(A, A$ID)))
#     ID num new
# 1.1  1   6  -4
# 1.2  1   2   6
# 1.3  1   8  NA
# 2.4  2   3   0
# 2.5  2   3  -2
# 2.6  2   1  NA
```

It's no secret that `do.call(rbind, ...)` is widely popular among R users.  But with the higher order functional programming functions on the `?Map` page (`Reduce`, `Filter`, etc), I thought there may be something I'm not aware of that can be a substitute for `do.call(rbind, ...)`  that will also reset the row names in the process.  I've tried the following.

```
> Reduce(function(x) { x$new <- c(diff(x$num), NA); x }, Map, split(A, A$ID))
# Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : unused argument (x[[i]])
> Reduce(function(x) { x$new <- c(diff(x$num), NA); x }, split(A, A$ID))
# Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : unused argument (x[[i]])
> Reduce(Map(function(x) { x$new <- c(diff(x$num), NA); x }, split(A, A$ID)))
# Error in Reduce(Map(function(x) { : 
#   argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

The exact result I want is obtained with

```
> M <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x) { x$new <- c(diff(x$num), NA); x }, 
                          split(A, A$ID)))
> rownames(M) <- NULL
> M
#   ID num new
# 1  1   6  -4
# 2  1   2   6
# 3  1   8  NA
# 4  2   3   0
# 5  2   3  -2
# 6  2   1  NA
```

Is there a higher order function that can replace `do.call(rbind, ...)` and incorporates `rownames(x) <- NULL` at the same time?

Note: I'm really looking for a `?Map` related answer, but am open to others.

Comment: You could `Reduce(rbind, Map...)` but why not just use `ave` or `aggregate` (or wrap a function on those) which hide `split`, `lapply` and `_bind`?

Comment: @alexis_laz - `Reduce(rbind, Map...)` is the specific answer I am looking or in this question.

Comment: one of you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I'd like @alexis_laz to post it.  It's not my answer.  He should get the credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at `rbindlist` from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(Map(function(x) { 
  x$new <- c(diff(x$num), NA)
  x}, split(A, A$ID)))
#    ID num new
# 1:  1   6  -4
# 2:  1   2   6
# 3:  1   8  NA
# 4:  2   3   0
# 5:  2   3  -2
# 6:  2   1  NA
```

However, the pure "data.table" approach is even more direct:

```
DT <- as.data.table(A)

DT[, new := c(diff(num), NA), by = ID][]
#    ID num new
# 1:  1   6  -4
# 2:  1   2   6
# 3:  1   8  NA
# 4:  2   3   0
# 5:  2   3  -2
# 6:  2   1  NA
```

Comment: would you be willing to explain what the `[]` at the end is doing ... ? (The rest makes sense to me.)

Comment: @BenBolker, that just prints the result.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably this split-apply-combine approach is what `plyr` is all about.  Not in base R, but effectively "higher-order".

```
library("plyr")
ddply(A,"ID",transform,new=c(diff(num),NA))
```

The `dplyr` version (apparently `transform` is not `dplyr`-aware: have to use `mutate` instead ...)

```
library("dplyr")
A %>% group_by("ID") %>% 
     mutate(new=c(diff(num),NA))
```

Comment: These are great. I've always taken the "why load a package if you don't have to" approach.  But nowadays it's almost silly not to take advantage of all the great packages out there.  Perhaps I should update the question to *Give me all your `do.call(rbind, ...)` replacements*.