# R - Expected speed of do.call(rbind,...)

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization, rbind, do.call

I have a list called `prebindgames` with a little over 2 million entries. Each list entry is a one-row dataframe with 6 columns. To give an idea of the type of the data in each column, each data frame is of the form:

```
data.frame(Time = double(),
           HScore = numeric(),
           AScore = numeric(),
           HTeam = character(),
           ATeam = character(),
           GameID = character(),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The numeric columns don't exceed the thousands, and the character columns don't exceed 10 characters. I tried running `do.call(rbind, prebindgames)`, and it ran overnight with no sign of stopping. I tried again for some smaller values:

```
start_time <- Sys.time()
allgamespbp <- do.call(rbind, prebindgames[1:1000]) 
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
Time difference of 1.059694 secs

prebindgames[1:10000]
Time difference of 11.00168 secs

prebindgames[1:20000]
Time differences of 37.30913 secs
```

So already I'm seeing some exponential ramping up, which would explain why things get out of hand when trying to bind all 2 million in one call. So my three questions are:

1) Is this normal? If I based my expected speed on a list with 10 thousand entries, it would only take about 40 minutes for 2 million

2) What can I do to speed this process up? From what I can tell, replacing values in a list of set length then using do.call is the most efficient way to bind rows together.

3) If this is as fast as I can get reasonably get it without major changes to my code or equipment, can I modify it to view my progress?

Background: This is for a webscraping project where I'll combine the scores from many NBA games into one large table. The entire code can be found here: https://github.com/NicholasHassan/NBAComeback

If you're curious about it, you can skip to line 54 of `NBA Comeback.R` and use `pbpurls.csv` to see what the scraping process is like.

Comment: You aren't wrong. When I did a simple experiment with 100 and 1000 columns, it seems that `ncol^2` was significant in predicting execution time of `rbind`ing (`ncol` is the number of columns), suggesting there is a non-linear relationship (weak regression here). (Not much of an answer, admittedly, just a "comment" that it seems a reasonable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a scenario where data.table could be dramatically (100-1000x) faster.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/concatenating-a-list-of-data-frames/

[Is there a higher order replacement for do.call(rbind, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553955/is-there-a-higher-order-replacement-for-do-callrbind)

Curious what your benchmarks say if you replace above with:

```
allgamespbp <- data.table::rbindlist(prebindgames[1:1000])
```

Comment: This is absolutely magical. I just did it for `rbindlist(prebindgames[1:20000])` in 0.22 seconds and `rbindlist(prebindgames[1:300000])` in 2.8 seconds. Practically scales linearly for my purposes at least. I do not have access to the whole list right now but even if it takes a long time, it is clearly multiple orders of magnitude faster. Thank you!